# Why jPlayer is not working with a m4a file?

Tags: jplayer, aac, m4a

There is an odd issue. When local url of m4a is played in chrome, it plays. When web url (hosted) is used, it opens file as text file. I believe due to similar reason jPlayer not plays it on my website. When play button is pressed no file is played (see in below link). It seems there is problem with m4a file because mp3 works well. I've tried to remove all the metadata (some were odd Lyrics tag) but it still not works. I've given the link of sample m4a file (1.5 MB).

Website url: [jPlayer webpage](http://visitstem.site11.com/pl/examples/blue.monday/demo-02.html)

File sample (also obtained by clicking "(m4a)" in site): [Link](http://visitstem.000webhostapp.com/ad/The%20Pink%20Panther%20Theme%20%C2%A7%20Henry%20Mancini%20&%20His%20Orchestra%20And%20Chorus.m4a)

Also mentioned below,
**Writing application** :
qaac 2.64, CoreAudioToolbox 7.9.8.3, AAC-LC Encoder

Mediainfo of one of the files:

```
Complete name :
/run/media/tejasvi/Big/Liesure/Music [defunct]/The Pink Panther Theme § Henry Mancini & His Orchestra And Chorus.m4a
Format :
MPEG-4
Format profile :
Apple audio with iTunes info
Codec ID :
M4A (M4A /mp42/isom)
File size :
1.77 MiB
Duration :
2 min 37 s
Overall bit rate mode :
Variable
Overall bit rate :
94.3 kb/s
Album :
The Pink Panther: Music from the Film Score Composed and Conducted by Henry Mancini
Track name :
The Pink Panther Theme (From the Mirisch-G & E Production 'The Pink Panther')
Performer :
Henry Mancini & His Orchestra And Chorus
Genre :
Films/Games
Recorded date :
2014
Encoded date :
UTC 2018-02-27 19:03:39
Tagged date :
UTC 2018-02-27 19:04:03
Writing application :
qaac 2.64, CoreAudioToolbox 7.9.8.3, AAC-LC Encoder, TVBR q36, Quality 96
Encoding Params :
(Binary)
Audio
ID :
1
Format :
AAC
Format/Info :
Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile :
LC
Codec ID :
mp4a-40-2
Duration :
2 min 37 s
Bit rate mode :
Variable
Bit rate :
92.7 kb/s
Channel(s) :
2 channels
Channel positions :
Front: L R
Sampling rate :
44.1 kHz
Frame rate :
43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode :
Lossy
Stream size :
1.74 MiB (98%)
Encoded date :
UTC 2018-02-27 19:03:39
Tagged date :
UTC 2018-02-27 19:04:03
```

Update: I have long forgotten about this question, but the error was likely due to incorrect Content-Type header since the file extension is disregarded by the browsers.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a more complete explanation of what doesn't work and what you've tried? That can assist us in helping you.

Comment: @Mozahler Primary problem: m4a not plays in jPlayer . Pertaining problems: weblink of *the* m4a files on my website open as text files (long page with unknown charaters).